# Parsing JSON feed with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I know this has been covered over and over but I just can't understand how to get started. Am too much of a JSON virgin to know what's going on.

I'm trying to get some data from a json feed on a remote server into a rails3 application.

I understand I need the json gem but I have no idea how to pull the data.

If the url is something like this:

http://my-feed.com/json?res=service&s=table&table=User&start=0&max=5&sort=id&desc=true

How do I go about getting that from my application?

Any help, walk-throughs, tutorials appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to make an HTTP request for the resource, grab the response, and (potentially) parse it yourself - although I think [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) will do the JSON parsing for you.  HTTParty would be my suggestion for making requests, though.

If you read the README, it links to [examples of how to use HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples) which you should find helpful.  The basic example includes how to make a get request, inspect the headers and body, etc.  I believe you can also use `response.parsed_response` to get the parsed response of whatever HTTParty's default parser is.  There is also an example of using your own custom parsers (if you prefer another to HTTParty's).

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of HTTparty and I like to party, so I'm going to look at that!

Comment: That's got it working perfectly. Can you suggest how I might style the output. Right now, it's just a bunch of garbage. Jz

Comment: It depends on your output, you should be able to find tons of CSS tutorials online though.  If you're looking for a way to output before styling, I'd suggest reading a [haml tutorial](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html) - I find it much more readable than ERB for views.  Just structure some HTML accordingly and use CSS to style it!

Comment: Cheers, I'll check it out. Found a way to get some of the variables out but need to figure it out. Can still not get my head around haml but maybe I'll try on this project. J

Comment: Make sure you use HTTParty 0.8.0 or later.  Previous versions used a buggy JSON decoder (Crack::JSON), which can cause a lot of grief if you're dealing with complex JSON responses.

Comment: FYI, the commit that fixed it is here: ["You can now party without crack"](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/commit/971e1d150f54f5627a82f39b7a3590fef6944da4).

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know the json gem - does it only handle the parsing?

If yes, and you only need to pull in the information, try this:

```
require 'open-uri'

begin
  json = open 'http://my-feed.com/json?res=service&s=table&table=User&start=0&max=5&sort=id&desc=true'
rescue
  # a multitude of HTTP-related errors can occur
end

json_string = json.read
# parse
```